# Get remaining delay time of a Task in libgdx

Tags: java, timer, libgdx

How do I get the remaining delay time of a Task that has been scheduled?

Let's say I schedule my `Task` like this:

```
Timer.schedule(myTask, 10);
```

How Do I get the remaining delay time before the Task is scheduled without counting the time myself?

Comment: What "Task" class are you using?

Comment: I'm using the "Task" provided by the libgdx framework. I just realized that I'm not  using the standard Task myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `getExecuteTimeMillis` which you can compare to `System.currentTimeMillis`.

[Source](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.Task.html)

Comment: Note (from the Javadoc): 
This method is typically invoked from within a task's run method, to determine whether the current execution of the task is sufficiently timely to warrant performing the scheduled activity